# install IntelliJ in Ubuntu come across the following problems

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: Unable to
>   detect graphics environment No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this
>   program performed an operation which requires it.
>       at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:62)

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu Server (hint: no GUI)? If running Ubuntu desktop the problem may be your graphics card. Post if desktop or server and tell us your graphics card.

Comment: I do it like this: Unpack .tar.gz archive and run bin/idea.sh